# Google Maps API and PHP

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code

http://jsfiddle.net/DanielMontenegro/7pdU4/3/

Now, supose that I want to put that map in a site to allow people to report some particular event through the geocoding service. I would like to ask how could I manage to get the address/coordinates of that event in a table, and gatherall the users reports into a single database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below code and try it.

I am using php static array you can connect your database and create array according your requirement. see the array below.

```
<?php  $item = array('jaipur, rajasthan,india', 'udaipur, rajasthan,india'); ?>
```

Below My Code Take a look.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyDwFjOazEAe1MI7nHV6vUwkWytOp8LH2Zk" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize();">
    <?php  $item = array('jaipur, rajasthan,india', 'udaipur, rajasthan,india'); ?>
    <script>
    var map = null;
    var geocoder = null;

    function initialize() {
            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {


                    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
                    var addresses = ["<?php echo implode ('","', $item); ?>"]


                    var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
                    //var addresses = ["A II Z, Ibn Battuta Mall, Sheikh Zayed Road, 5th Interchange, Jebel Ali Village, Dubai","A. Testoni,Dubai Festival City Mall, Ground Floor, Dubai", "Abdulla Hussain Khunji, The Dubai Mall,Downtown, Abu Dhabi"];
                    var curIndex = 0;

                    function showAddress() {
                      var _cur = addresses[curIndex];
                      geocoder.getLatLng(
                        _cur,
                        function(point) {
                          if (!point) {
                            //alert(_cur + " not found");
                            //map.setCenter(new GLatLng(0, 0), 6);
                            //map.setUIToDefault();
                          } else {
                            //console.log(_cur+":"+point);
                            //alert(_cur);
                                    var cafeIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);

                                    // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
                                    markerOptions = { icon:cafeIcon };

                                    map.setCenter(point, 6);
                                    var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
                                    map.addOverlay(marker);

                                    var sales = new Array();
                                    sales = _cur.split("|");


                                    //Add click event on push pin to open info window on click of the icon
                                    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                                            marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<p class='para1bold' style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Address <br /><span class='para1' style='font-weight:normal;'>" + sales[1] + "</span></p>");
                                    });
                                    //Provides map,satellite,hybrid and terrain views in the map along with zoom control


                                    map.setUIToDefault();
                          }
                          //do next after done

                          curIndex++;

                          if(curIndex<addresses.length)
                            showAddress();
                        }
                      );
                    }
                    showAddress();
       }  
    }
    </script>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:750px;"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of goood information about interfacing the Google Maps API v3 with PHP/MySQL in the ["Articles" section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/)

This one looks like it answers your question; [From Info Windows to a Database: Saving User-Added Form Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set up an action listener of some kind (preferably a listener that will listen for a user click on the map). Then, simply geocode the resulting lat/lng and store what you receive in your table.

1. User clicks a point on map.
2. Click event grabs what lat/lng the user clicked on.
3. The Lat/lng is geocoded for a textual address using Ajax.
4. Both Lat/lng and textual address are stored side-by-side in your database table.